# My code got "R session aborted" on Rstudio, while succeeded on a online compiler

Tags: r, rstudio

```
library(ggplot2)
text<-"
name,date,value
PLT,2017-01-01,40
PLT,2017-01-03,37
"
mydata<-read.table(header=TRUE,sep=",",text=text)
mydata$date<-as.Date(mydata$date)
ggplot(mydata,aes(date,value))+geom_line()
```

The code above got "R session aborted" on Rstudio, while succeeded on a online compiler.

Comment: This worked fine on my machine. You might want to start a fresh R session and try this again.

Comment: shut down R completely and reinstall ggplot2. though you may have corrupt shared libraries and may need to reinstall R. but ggplot2 uses packages with compiled code and you may just need to reinstall it and it's dependencies.

Comment: I run the code in Rgui and it works, so I think my Rstudio may have some problem. But I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I run the code in Rgui and it works, so I think my Rstudio may have some problem. But I still don't know why.